# ValueError/ data cardinality ambiguity in Conv1D and Conv2D training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to understand and apply CNN for a project and to that end, I'm unable to resplve the input shape issue which I've been able to resolve in case of SimpleRNN and LSTM. As I understand, the input_shape for Conv1D is (batch_size, steps, input_dim) and in case of Conv2D is (batch_size, (image_dim), channels) thus I reshaped x and y as
x -> (60, 1322, 1295, 1)
y -> (12, 1322, 1295, 1)

and I'm receiving a data cardinality error due to inconsistent number of samples (60 and 12). Need some help here.

```
pathx = os.path.join(r'/Users/trainx')
pathy = os.path.join(r'/Users/trainy')

xdir = glob(os.path.join(pathx, "*.tif"))
ydir = glob(os.path.join(pathy, "*.tif"))
xdir.sort()
ydir.sort()

evi = rioxarray.open_rasterio('/evi.tif')
lst = rioxarray.open_rasterio('lst.tif')
ndbi = rioxarray.open_rasterio('ndbi.tif')
ndwi = rioxarray.open_rasterio('ndwi.tif')
yei = rioxarray.open_rasterio('y.tif')

x = numpy.hstack([evi, lst, ndbi, ndwi])
x = x.reshape(-1, 1322, 1295, 1)
y = yei
y = yei.values
# y= yei.to_masked_array()
type(y)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1322, 1295, 1)
x.shape, y.shape

x = x.astype("float") / 255.0

from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(x[0].shape)))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x,y, batch_size=10, epochs=10)
```

Here's the model.summary():

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 1318, 1291, 32)    832       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 659, 645, 32)     0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten_30 (Flatten)        (None, 13601760)          0         
                                                                 
 dense_47 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 13601761  
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13,602,593
Trainable params: 13,602,593
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

And the resultant error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [257], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(x,y, batch_size=10, epochs=10)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/cestlavie/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/cestlavie/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py:1851, in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1844     msg += "  {} sizes: {}\n".format(
   1845         label,
   1846         ", ".join(
   1847             str(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(single_data)
   1848         ),
   1849     )
   1850 msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1851 raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 60
  y sizes: 12
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

Comment: Your code is not executable and your error therefore not reproducible.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Your x and y clearly have different batch sizes, as you mention yourself. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: As I posted this I was not aware that CNN cannot be run on multiple inputs thus the question; now that I realise that I'm looking at other models for running the input data